# GitLab wiki and special characters

Tags: character-encoding, gitlab

I have installed GitLab on a virtual Ubuntu Server 64bit, and everything works fine.

I have noticed that if I write inside a Wiki page a special character, for example:

```
èàì
```

The characters are shown with strange symbols:

[image: Imgur]

Neither if I write the HTML code the characters are displayed in the right way.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As commented in [issue 975](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/975), it can depend on the database you are using:
for mysql, check your encoding, as mentioned in the [database document](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/databases.md).

The base is supposed to be created with:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `gitlabhq_production` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`;
```

Otherwise, that would imply some ruby code issue, as [mentioned in issue 3183](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/3183#issuecomment-15366787).

---

The [OP Fez Vrasta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059996/fez-vrasta) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607051/gitlab-wiki-and-special-characters#comment29107412_19608713) it must be a local browser-related issue.

It can be:

- an [encoding issue](https://superuser.com/a/425523/141)
- some character which [would be displayed properly as HTML code](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/character-coding-problem-in-chrome-and-ie?replies=2)

Comment: The database is already in utf8, I've followed the official installation doc. I'm talking about the default wiki of gitlab, no plugins. the plain gitlab installation (latest version) on a completely new ubuntu server. The problem occurs even while I write in the editor.

Comment: @FezVrasta Is it more a *local* setting issue, like one related to the browser you are using, as in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1536811&p=10000621#post10000621 for instance?

Comment: Looks like a browser problem, yes. On Internet Explorer 10 it works. But on Chrome the problem is only on GitLab for what I see...